# 2d median filter of arbitrary x,y coordinates in matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, vectorization, median

I have a set of x,y coordinates and intensity (x,y,I). These x,y coordinates are not uniform and do not form an ordered 2d array. I'd like to 2D median filter the intensity based on the x,y coordinates . Unfortunately I cant simply use `medfilt2` because they are not ordered or uniformly spaced.
What I tried:

1. make a map of the neighborhood of each (x,y) coordinate:

   ```
   for i=1:numel(x)

    neighbo{i}=find(sqrt( (x-x(i)).^2+(y-y(i)).^2)<150);

   end
   ```

this is already a problem as the the vector `x` is 1e7 long, and it takes really a long time just to do that.

next I'd sort each neighbo{i} and pick the central value, I can just imagine it would take just as long.
Any advice on how to achieve that median filtering, or make the above more efficient ?

Comment: Take a look at R-trees or R*-trees. They make it cheap to find all points within a certain distance of a given coordinate.

Comment: ok, very cool, but I guess I dont understand how to implement this to relate to my question...